# React Firebase displayName is returning null unless page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Firebase and using it for the first time to create a user system where you can sign up, login, and logout using Firebase authentication. There is a username state variable, and also a user state variable. Upon sign up the username is stored correctly, however the user variable is still returning null unless I refresh the page, then after the user shows correctly. Is there something that I'm missing?

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const [openSignIn, setOpenSignIn] = useState(false);
const [modalStyle] = useState(getModalStyle);
const classes = useStyles();
const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);


useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
    if (authUser) {
      // user is logged in...
      console.log(authUser);
      setUser(authUser.displayName);

      if (authUser.displayName) {
        
      } else {
        //if user was just created
        return authUser.updateProfile({
          displayName: username,
        });
      }
    } else {
      setUser(null);
    }
  });

  return () => {
    unsubscribe();
  };
}, [user, username]);

  const signUp = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((authUser) => {
        authUser.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: username
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
    
    setOpen(false)
  }
  
  const signIn = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  
    setOpenSignIn(false)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of the web SDK (since v4.0.0 in May 2017), when the [`Auth#onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) listener is fired changed to only on sign-in and sign-out but it used to be any changes to the ID token associated with the user (like updating the `displayName`). If you wanted to revert to the old functionality, you would instead use [`Auth#onIdTokenChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged).

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = auth.onIdTokenChanged((authUser) => {
    if (authUser) {
      // user is logged in...
      console.log(authUser);
      setUser(authUser.displayName);

      if (authUser.displayName) {
        
      } else {
        //if user was just created
        return authUser.updateProfile({
          displayName: username,
        });
      }
    } else {
      setUser(null);
    }
  });

  return () => {
    unsubscribe();
  };
}, [user, username]);
```

I recommend renaming `user` to something else like `userDisplayName` as you should reserve `user` for use with instances of `firebase.auth.User`. This will prevent confusion with other code samples you stumble across.

Personally, I would recommend splitting this functionality out of the `onAuthStateChanged` handler like so:

```
// outside your component
function updateDisplayName(user, username) {
  if (!user) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error("You must be signed in first!"));
  }
  
  return user.updateProfile({
    displayName: username
  });
}
```

```
// inside your component

// user == undefined -> still verifying auth token
// user == null -> signed out
// user is a firebase.user.User -> user signed in
const [user, setUser] = useState(() => firebase.auth().currentUser || undefined);
// username == null -> signed out/still verifying user token/displayName not set
// username is a string -> user signed in & displayName set
const [username, setUsername] = useState(user ? user.displayName : null);
// userIsLoading == true -> still verifying user token, lock the form/show loading icon
// userIsLoading == false -> `user` is resolved and ready for use
const userIsLoading = user === undefined;

// a value to store the proposed new username, connect this to an input
const [newUsername, setNewUsername] = useState("");
// an error message for the input of `newUsername`
const [usernameError, setUsernameError] = useState(null); 

// keep `user` & `username` (if available) up to date
useEffect(() => auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  setUser(user);
  setUsername(user ? user.displayName : null);
}), []);

// attach this to a button - don't connect to "onChange" of "newUsername"
// note: this returns a Promise that finishes when the username was either updated or failed to update
const onChangeUsernameSubmit = () => {
  return updateDisplayName(user, newUsername)
    .then(() => {
      // updated successfully. update state
      setUsername(newUsername);
      setUsernameError(null);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // failed to change username. invalid value? expired token?
      setUsernameError("username not changed: " + (err.message || "something unexpected went wrong"));
    });
}
```